# Add width and height to every timage on html page with php automatically

Tags: php

I am trying to add automatically width and height to all images from the page but for some reason it's adding about 3 times the width and height to the image and it's working very hard. From my tests `getimagesize` function is the issue of loading hard, but for repeating the width and height on every img tag 3 time I don't get it.

REGEX VERSION

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.inspiredhealing.org');
$html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
$html = preg_replace( '/(width)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
$html = str_replace('width="60"', '', $html);
$img_sources = preg_match_all('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $html, $images);
foreach($images[1] as $src) {
    $image_size = getimagesize($src);
    $html = str_replace($src.'"', $src.'" '.$image_size[3], $html);
}
var_dump($html);
```

DOM DOCUMENT VERSION

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.inspiredhealing.org');
$dom = new domDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
$html = preg_replace( '/(width)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
$html = str_replace('width="60"', '', $html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$img_sources = array();
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if($image->getAttribute('src') !== '') {
        array_push($img_sources, $image->getAttribute('src'));
    }
}
foreach($img_sources as $src) {
    $image_size = getimagesize($src);
    var_dump($image_size);
    //$html = str_replace($src.'"', $src.'" '.$image_size[3], $html);
}
var_dump($html);
```

I added the version with dom document, but still script runs slow and it gets to the image the width and height attribute 5 times, it's true that in the array I get 5 times same link, but how to add correctly. Array `$img_sources` would be smth like this:

```
array(
     'fb.png', 
     'fb.png',
     'fb.png'
....
)
```

so it ads to the same tags but on all instanced of fb.png 5 times the width and height instead of adding it 1 time to each element of the array. So the issue stands in the `foreach($img_sources as $src) {` but how to overcome this.

Comment: why are you using regexes? you should be using a DOM parser...

Comment: @MarcB Would `$html` variable remain string? And more exactly how to do that?

Comment: no. it wouldn't be a string. it'd be a DOM object. but from that object you can trivially retrieve the full html anyways.

Comment: @MarcB Updated my question, it seams that regex is not the issue but the foreach is, I have same image x times for about x images, and for some reason is applying the width and height of the image 5 times to all 5 images.

Comment: I saw smth related to preg_replace callback, but don't understand exactly how to use it.